# Mysql temporarily suppress unique index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-update

I have a table with unique index on two columns, id_parent and sort_order to be precise

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | id_parent | sort_order | some_data   | other_data  | more_data   |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1  |         1 |          1 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum |
| 2  |         1 |          2 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum |
| 3  |         1 |          3 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to update them, their data and their sort_order in one-go. sort_order would change from `1 - 2 - 3` to, for example `2 - 3 - 1`.

But when I start running update statements, unique index block me, just as expected, saying that I can't have two rows with `id_parent = 1 and sort_order = 2`.
Well, I could set it 4 for now, update other rows in correct order, and then set this one.
But then, I would have to run an extra statement, and most probably add additional logic to my scripting language to determine correct order of updates.
I also use ORM, and it becomes even more inconvinient.

My question now, is there some method to make mysql temporarily ignore this index? Like starting a special transaction, in which indexes would be calculated only right before commiting it?

Comment: Are your tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Drop the unique key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172188/5381704. Later add it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know that isn't possible.

The only time I've seen anything like that is that you can disable non unique keys on myisam tables. But not on InnoDB and not on unique keys.

However, to save you an update or two, there is no need to have the exact number 1, 2 and 3. You could as well have 4, 5 and 6. Right? You would use it in a order by and nothing else so the exact numbers aren't important. It will even save you an update if you're clever. From your example

```
update table set sort_order = 4 where sort_order = 1 and id = 1 and id_parent = 1;
```

New sort order is 2, 3, 1. And in just one update.

Comment: Shame on me, using 4-5-6 was so obivious.

Comment: Agree about that being impossible with multiple updates. However updating them in a single statement might work. Either way, it's +1 for a solution that is clear and simple.

Answer (score 6):

### MyISAM

For MyISAM tables, you can simply add this line at the start of your script:

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
```

It's common to use this in conjunction with:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

The `UNIQUE_CHECKS` variable is mentioned in the docs here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

### InnoDB

There seem to be reports that the above commands don't work with the InnoDB engine. If so, then you can try dropping the `UNIQUE` index temporarily and then adding it back.

See: [How to remove unique key from mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9172164/195835)

Feel free to edit this post and improve it with a code example if you have one.

Comment: Just tried this on 5.6, does NOT work with InnoDB. Duplicate key still threw an error.

Comment: @bluecollarcoder Did you try setting *both* `UNIQUE_CHECKS` and `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to zero?  And are you sure you are not duplicating a *primary key* which is probably still not allowed?

Comment: The unique key is on a column that does not reference any other table, so `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is irrelevant here. And the column with unique key is definitely not a part of the primary key.

In what situation were you able to get `UNIQUE_CHECKS=0` to work as expected in this case?

Comment: Quote from Mysql documentation: `unique_checks permits but does not require storage engines to ignore duplicate keys.` It would seem that Innodb does not support this feature.

Comment: @Simon, Doesn't work for me too (windows 8.1, mysql 5.6.22). How can we **force** the behavior of `unique_checks=0`?

Comment: SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;-will not help you to temporarily suppress unique key.
If set to 0,storage engines are allowed to assume that duplicate keys are not present in input data. If you know for certain that your data does not contain uniqueness violations, you can set this to 0.
Note that setting this variable to 0 does not require storage engines to ignore duplicate keys,it will still issue  duplicate-key 
errors if any detects

Comment: The problem is often your unique index is on a field that's also a foreign key. if you remove the FK first, then setting UNIQUE_CHECKS may work. You can also remove FK first, then remove your unique constraint, then add them back in reverse order. That's what I do sometimes.

Comment: I get 1062 error even after I do `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;` and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`.

Comment: @bluecollarcoder A column with a unique index also can be a foreign key!

Answer (score 5):

*‘But when I start running update **statements**…’* – I understand, you tried updating the values using multiple UPDATE statement, like in a loop. Is that so? How about updating them in one go? Like this, for example:

```
UPDATE atable
SET sort_order = CASE sort_order WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE sort_order + 1 END
WHERE id_parent = 1
  AND sort_order BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

A single statement is atomic, so, by the time this update ends, the values of `sort_order`, although changed, remain unique.

I can't test this in MySQL, sorry, but it definitely works in SQL Server, and I believe the behaviour respects the standards.

Comment: Have not thought of it. Would be pain to use with ORM, though. This is closer to correct answer on specified question then answer by Andreas, but I probably will end up using his advice. What should I do with selected answer in this case? Give it to answer I'm going to use, or to answer which is closer on topic?

Comment: Well, in case when more than one answer matches the *question*, you should probably go with the one that you are going to apply to solve the *actual problem*. So it's probably Andreas's answer that you should choose. Other considerations might exist, though. I'm fine with your decision, anyway!

Comment: That won't work unless the rows are actually updated in the correct order. No time during execution may the unique key be violated. `update sorttest set sort = sort+1 order by sort desc;` won't work without the descending sort, the first row would violate the key, even if the second row is about to be moved out of place.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand: Thanks for the feedback. I can't say anything with regard to MySQL, but my query does work in SQL Server. Your example works too, only without ORDER BY, as SQL Server doesn't allow ORDER BY in an UPDATE statement. You are right in saying that the unique key on the column gets violated during the execution, but (in SQL Server) the constraint doesn't come into effect until after the statement is done updating. And since the final data do not contain any duplicates, no exception occurs, and, consequently, no roll-back either.

Comment: Updating in one go also works well in Oracle. I feel frustrated with mysql.