# MySQL how to update multiple rows without breaking unique constraint or using placeholder row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint

In MySQL,
I have a table named `Channel` (Auto-generated by Prisma ORM)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Channel` (
    `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `guildId` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NULL,
    `createdAt` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    `position` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `parentId` INTEGER NULL,
    `ratelimit` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `type` ENUM('textChannel', 'categoryChannel') NOT NULL,

    INDEX `Channel_guildId_idx`(`guildId`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Channel_guildId_name_key`(`guildId`, `name`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Channel_guildId_position_key`(`guildId`, `position`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

As you can see, there's a UNIQUE INDEX constraint `Channel_guildId_position_key`

How can I do something that doesn't break this unique constraint such that: (I can get all the rows with the same guild_id with `SELECT * FROM Channel WHERE guildId = $guildId`)

update a channel `current`'s position field value to `x` (assuming x is bigger than `current.position`)
update all channels between `current.position` and position `x` and decrement their position field by `1`
update `current.position` to position `x`

Basically, I want to move a channel to a position and everything in between new position and old position needs to advance forward. But I'm getting blocked by the constraint I set which makes `(position, guildId)` a unique identifier, and thus requiring a temporary value to accomplish this task. I'm looking for a one-operation solution that doesn't break the constraint

Note: This includes (possibly) more than two rows, and a single swap won't work.

If you still do not understand the question, think of chat channels, when client drags a channel to a different position I want to update all the positions of the channels that are "in between" the "before" and "after" positions.

Example:
Here the table has 3 rows

```sql
INSERT INTO Channel (id, guildId, name, position, type) VALUES (1, 1, 'ch1', 1, 'textChannel');
INSERT INTO Channel (id, guildId, name, position, type) VALUES (2, 1, 'ch2', 2, 'textChannel');
INSERT INTO Channel (id, guildId, name, position, type) VALUES (3, 1, 'ch3', 3, 'textChannel');
```

Now, let's say I want to move channel 'ch3' to position 1, then 'ch1' and 'ch2''s position would be changed to 2, 3 respectively.
But if I run these operations: (Assuming I got the IDs already)

$guildId = 0

$originalPositionOfChannel3 = 3

$newPosition = 0

````sql
UPDATE Channel SET position = $newPosition WHERE guildId = $guildId AND name = 'ch3';
UPDATE Channel SET position = position + 1 WHERE guildId = $guildId AND position < $originalPositionOfChannel3 AND position >= $newPosition;```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410844/mysql-temporarily-suppress-unique-index

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understood the answers, but most of them were telling me to temporarily disable the constraint... the accepted answer said to use "4-5-6", which isn't going to work in my case because I'm actually getting these channels into an array... which I don't want empty spots in

Comment: It would be helpful (to me at least) to add a small before/after example to the question.

Comment: Provide reproduceable sample - CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO with sample data (5-7 rows), desired final data state with detailed explanations.